# Nginx Bulk URL Redirect

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I mapped URL in Nginx ( Bulk Level of Redirect)

nginx.conf

```
map $uri $new_url2{
  include /var/www/html/**ext.map**;
}

=== **ext.map** Inside File
/en_us/abc.html /en_us/abc22.html;
/it_it/abc.html /it_it/abc22.html;
/fr_fr/abc.html /fr_fr/abc22.html;
```

nginx_host.conf

```
if ($new_url2)
        {
                return 301 $new_url2;
                break;
        }
```

It's working fine. Because of location block in URL, I need to generate multiple times for individual country wise.

I am trying to capture the location section and add with redirect URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *regular expression* in the `map` block by introducing it with a `~` or `~*`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

Use a *named capture* to record the language code so that it can be used to construct the new URI. Use double quotes around an expression that contains braces `{}`.

For example:

```
"~*^(?<lang>/\w{2}_\w{2})/abc.html" $lang/abc22.html;
```

Comment: map $uri $new_url3 {
  ~*^(?<lang>/\w{2}_\w{2})/$uri $lang/$new_url3;
  include /var/www/html/exttest.map;
} === Not working